# Live Tiles UWP Windows 10 - Not Update livetiles queue

Tags: c#, xml, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, live-tile

I Have an problem, and I do not identify what are wrong. I use Notification Visualizer app for preview my Tiles.

I have one XML template, and this work with somes images and for another not work, by example:

My Template XML for tile:

```
    <tile>
  <visual branding="nameAndLogo">
    <binding template="TileMedium">
          <image src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/fantendo/images/2/25/Mario_Artwork_-_Super_Mario_3D_World.png/revision/latest?cb=20131025223058.png" placement="peek" hint-overlay="20"/> 
          <image src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/media.eremedia.com/uploads/2012/08/24111405/stackoverflow-logo-700x467.png" placement="background"/> 
    </binding>
  </visual>
</tile>
```

The problem are:

Url 1 (Work - Applied on template above) = "http://gcn.net.br/dir-arquivo-imagem/2015/09/20150914133707_34730594.jpg"

Url 2 (not work - If you change url above for this) = "http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/fantendo/images/2/25/Mario_Artwork_-_Super_Mario_3D_World.png/revision/latest?cb=20131025223058.png"

When i put this template on Notification Visualizer app, the preview work perfectly but when I pin the Tile, not work. The problem are the same when I apply this on my application.

Why tile work with some url and anothers not work?

Someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868303/how-to-resize-bitmap-image-to-be-200-kb-and-meet-tile-restrictions-winrt

Answer (score 4):

There is a [200KB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn455106(v=vs.85).aspx) (and 1024x1024 pixel limit) on images that are shown on tile updates. The image pointed to in your second URL is above this limit, which explains why the update is not being rendered.

Comment: Thank a lot.
Explain my problem :)
What you recommend for solve this problem?

Comment: If you own the service hosting the images, it's just a matter of scaling down the images so that they fit within the constraints. If you don't own the service, you could run them through another image service to shrink the sizes, or download them perform the task locally (the linked question talks about the latter).

Comment: Kucha, my solution are: download images from local storage and resize that. After that, use local url to inject images on live tile.